# Does Arduino board have CMOS or TTL gates?

Tags: arduino

Arduino board has a microcontroller called Atmega328. I wonder if it is CMOS or TTL. I dont know how to understand it from the datasheet. Second question is on the Arduino board there are other chips. Are they all TTL or CMOS? How can I know?

Comment: *"How can I know?"* - but why would we want to? Anything we *need* to know should be in the datasheets. For 99.99% of uses, it could filled with little blue imps - so long as it does what the datasheet says.

Comment: I always thought it was "magic smoke" ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which logic gate family is used in a PC? TTL or CMOS?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87839/which-logic-gate-family-is-used-in-a-pc-ttl-or-cmos)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the key facts about a chip should be contained in its datasheet. This should *always* be your first port of call when researching things.

[Atmega328 datasheet.](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CGYQFjAB&url=http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf&ei=fo17UpPfBOie0QXwhYHwBA&usg=AFQjCNFcwQZ1S5ZXKLGwKQ_u54ggN55CkQ&sig2=khp9uEYsEwca0xjS-2RIIQ&bvm=bv.56146854,d.d2k)

Search for "CMOS". First hit is page 5:

"The ATmega48PA/88PA/168PA/328P is a low-power CMOS 8-bit microcontroller based on the
AVR enhanced RISC architecture".

**Bonus answer**: a quick look at the Arduino UNO schematic shows three different voltage regulators, and an LM358D used as a comparator, all of which are considered "analog" parts and neither CMOS nor TTL.

Comment: intersting. i thought any component nowadays should be eirther ttl or cmos ??

Comment: @user16307 Where did you get the impression that any component must be either TTL or CMOS?

Comment: i mean in a circuitry why to use several different locig gates so one has to use interfaces to make them work together. where am i wrong?:( also isnt it cmos and ttl the most common ones?

Comment: "There are more things in heaven and earth than are dreamt of in your philosophy": TTL/CMOS is not an exhaustive classification! Semiconductor design has a fairly sharp demarcation between digital and analog, and analog devices may comprise whatever mix of bipolar and FET transistors they need to go the job. You're correct that you don't get TTL _and_ CMOS on the same device, and a larger system will stick to one of those two, but there are more kinds of chip! It's a bit like saying all fruit is _either_ apple _or_ orange.

Comment: Further upsetting this worldview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family It appears that a variant of ECL is still in use: http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slla120/slla120.pdf but otherwise digital is almost always CMOS.

Comment: @user16307: The dichotomy you're looking for is "bipolar/MOSFET". And even that's not true, in a few places.

Answer (score 2):

The Atmega328 processor is CMOS.  The other stuff is whatever the board designers decided to use, but most likely CMOS.  However, instead of asking for heresay, go look at the schematic and BOM and see directly.